# How to define upvote/downvote when using acts_as_votable for comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have my comments resource nested in my posts resource, and both resources act_as_votable.

How would I go about defining upvote/downvote?  Here is how I am doing it now(comments controller)  :

```
def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comment.find(params[:post_id])
    @post.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to posts_path
end

   def downvote
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     @comment = @post.comment.find(params[:post_id])
     @post.downvote_by current_user
     redirect_to posts_path
   end
```

Here is new and create action and params:

```
def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:id])
 end


def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
  @comment.post_id = @post.id 
if @comment.save
  redirect_to @post
else

  redirect_to new_post_comment_path(post)
end
end

private

   def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :post_id)
```

end

This is the error message I've been getting:

```
 No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"comment", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, 
 :post_id=>#<Comment id: 22, body: "test", user_id: 1, post_id: 4, created_at:         

 "2014-10-14 07:28:22", updated_at: "2014-10-14 07:28:22", cached_votes_total: 0,       

 cached_votes_score: 0, cached_votes_up: 0, cached_votes_down: 0,   

 cached_weighted_score: 0, cached_weighted_total: 0, cached_weighted_average: 0.0>} 
 missing required keys: [:id]
```

My nested routes:

```
  resources :posts do
member do
  put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
  put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
end
resources :comments do
member do
  get 'upvote' => 'comment#upvote', as: :upvote
  get 'downvote' => 'comment#downvote', as: :downvote
end
end
end
```

comments/index.html.erb:

```
<div class="comments">
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<p><%= comment.body %></p>


<div>
  <%= link_to "up", upvote_post_comment_path(comment) %>
  <%= link_to "down", downvote_post_comment_path(comment) %>
  <%= comment.score %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I see two questions here.  First, a design question: where should the upvote and downvote actions live, ie. should they be non-resourceful actions in the comments controller?  Second, a routing question: how to add routes for the new actions?  Which question would you like us to focus on? :)

Comment: The routing question, error message, and whether my non resourceful actions are properly set up.

Comment: What does the relevant part of your route file look like?

Comment: Added the relevant routes in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is this hint at the end of the "No route matches" error:

```
missing required keys: [:id]
```

I'm guessing your `Comment` object has a `nil` `id`.  Maybe it has not been persisted yet?

Also, possibly unrelated, you have an ambiguous route:

```
resources :comments do
  member do
    get 'upvote' => 'comment#upvote', as: :upvote
    get 'upvote' => 'comment#downvote', as: :downvote
  end
end
```

See how `/comments/:id/upvote` routes to two different actions?

Comment: I fixed the dual upvote route thanks.  I know the :id is nil, but I can't figure out what is wrong.  What debugging tools should I use or resources should I look at?

Comment: It's probably the link to upvote / downvote that is broken (specifically the ID part of it). Could you show the links please?

Comment: I think `upvote_post_comment_path` takes two arguments, the post and the comment.  See how it's trying to use your comment instance as the `post_id`?